# Can a texture be bound to more than one fbo?

Tags: opengl, fbo

Can the same texture be bound to more than one framebuffer object?
I need to write on some texture in a multi target rendering pass with a certain fbo, and later to add some blending to just one of those texture, so I need a second framebuffer object with that texture bound to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea why you would think that you can't *attach* a texture to multiple FBOs. So yes, you can.

However, you shouldn't need to for your purposes. You don't have to write to *all* of the images attached to an FBO. You [control what images get written to](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Draw_color_buffers) with [`glDrawBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawBuffers). You can even [selectively enable and disable blending to certain draw buffers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Blend_enabling), if you need to write to multiple buffers but only blend with certain ones.

So yes you can, but you shouldn't bother. Just switch your draw buffers, unless you need a new depth buffer or something.

Comment: What if I want to read from a texture bound to the same FBO I am writing to? Let's say I have my FBO with TextureA and TextureB,  bound to it. I want to blend TextureB on TextureA. It's ok if I just change glDrawBuffers to render only on TextureA? In other words, can I read from a texture when I am writing on an FBO to which such texture is bound, if I don't write to that specific texture?

Comment: @darius: That's an entirely new question. So use the Ask a Question button to ask it. Or just [look up the answer on the OpenGL Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Framebuffer_objects).